# Terraform- read list of objects from yaml file

Tags: yaml, terraform, devops

I want to read a list of objects from a yaml file via terraform code and map it to a local variable. Also i need search an object with a key and get the values from a yaml file. Can anyone suggest suitable solution?

my yaml file looks like below. Here use will be the primary key

```
list_details:
 some_list:
 - use: a
   path: somepath
   description : "some description"

 - use: b
   path: somepath2
   description : "some description 2"
```

I have loaded the yaml file in my variable section in Terraform like this

```
locals {
 list  = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/mylist.yaml"))
}
```

Now the problem is how I can get one object with its values by passing the "use" value to the list?
"

Comment: "passing the "use" value to the list?" - what do you mean by that? Do you have any example?

Comment: For Eg:- I should be able to search the object from list by passing the value "a" and get path and description for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `use` values are unique, you can re-organize your list into map:

```
locals {
  list_as_map = {for val in local.list["list_details"]["some_list"]:
                 val["use"] => val["path"]}
}
```

which gives `list_as_map` as:

```
  "a" = "somepath"
  "b" = "somepath2"
```

then you access the `path` based on a value of `use`:

```
path_for_a = local.list_as_map["a"]
```

**Update**

If you want to keep description, its better to do:

```
  list_as_map = {for val in local.list["list_details"]["some_list"]:
                 val["use"] => {
                       path = val["path"]
                       description = val["description"]
                       }  
                 }
```

then you access the `path` or `description` as:

```
local.list_as_map["a"].path
local.list_as_map["a"].description
```

Comment: @marcin- Thank you very much. it worked well. One more doubt since I'm new to Terraform. Do we need to create separate variables for other values like description? How we can get the values like local.list_as_map["a"].description ?

Comment: @ByteCruncher I updated the answer for `local.list_as_map["a"].description` to work.